# Multipart form encoding file upload in Python 3

Tags: forms, post, python-3.x, multipart

I was wondering if it was possible to post to a form with `enctype='multipart/form-data'` in Python 3. I looked around and could only find things for Python 2 (such as poster).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use [requests](http://docs.python-requests.org/en/latest/), it supports python 3.

```
import requests

response = requests.post('http://httpbin.org/post', files={'file': open('filename','rb')})
print(response.content)
```